# strophe js not working after installing ssl certificate

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am developing a real time application for that i had installed openfire and using strophe js to integrate it on client side and everything works fine

but later on we had to integrate ssl certificate to website and after adding ssl certificate strophe stops working and giving error

i had added self attested certificates in openfire too but still no use 
[image: error visible in browser]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with your web server config and not strophe. Speculating based on the little info I have about your configuration I would guess that openfire bosh config is listening on a port other than the default ssl 443 port.

You will either need to specify the port number openfire is listening on (adventurefriend.com:8443 or something) or use an http rewrite in your Apache config to rewrite requests with ^/http-bind to that port.